# Autonumbering equations in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Is is possible to number automatic number equations in doxygen markdown documentation?

Example:

page1.md:

```
This is Equation 1:

\f[
\label{Eq:1}
\bbox[Pearl, 10px,border:1px solid black]
{
    \rho = \frac{m}{V}
}
\f]
```

If I put a `\tag{#numberOfTheEquation}` I will get the number.

But has you build the document it is very inconvenient to change every equation number if one inserts a new equation in the middle of the document.

Best Regards!

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Using fixed numbers is of course not a good idea what is your output format?

Answer (score 1):

When we have a file like:

```
/** \file

# Math references

\f{equation}{
\alpha = \beta * \gamma
  \label{eq:my_system}
\f}

The reference: \f$\eqref{eq:my_system}\f$

*/
```

We can use a `Doxyfile` like:

```
USE_MATHJAX = YES
EXTRA_PACKAGES = amsmath amssymb
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = amssymb amsmath
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       = mycode.js
```

with `mycode.js`:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
```

This will result in:

[image]

Comment: Based on your question I also looked at the output in case MathJax was not used and here the reference was `??` instead of `1`.  For this I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8691, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8691).